# how to design an api for sending sms

Tags: c#, api, sms

I want to design an API for sending SMS through various websites like **way2sms, fullonsms** etc.. I tried several APIs like [this](http://ultimatesmsapi.tk) and also [this one](http://ubaid.tk) but I am thinking of designing my own because of the traffic on their servers. Any idea about how to start. I am good at coding in C#. The link they currently provide to send sms is like this

```
http://ultimatesmsapi.tk/sms.php?provider=way2sms&username=9876543210&password=9876543210&numbers=9876543210&msg=your%20msg
```

and

```
http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=9876543210&pwd=mypassword&msg=myMEssage&phone=9876543210&provider=way2sms
```

Comment: Are you going to use your own SMS servers and utilities?

Comment: @NewAmbition yes i am ready to use my own server and utilities

Comment: @Mamta Dalal what changes did u make?

Comment: Edited the grammar. Changed "a" to "an" etc. Technical part of the question is untouched, I made only grammar related changes.

Comment: Good initiative.
You can make use of webservices in c#.
They are strong and platform independent source in c# .net. Further help about webservices :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx
and
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured it myself... This thing can be achieved by emulating a web browser.